# I opened my phone and tore the power circuit, can it be joined back?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-ace, power-on

I wanted to reseat my phone speaker because it wasn't working. In the process of dismantling my phone, I tore the power button's circuit. What kind of adhesive can I usually use to join it back together? Or I am pretty much screwed?

Comment: That may describe to you what happened, but it is not enough information to know how it is damaged. Did you peel off traces, just pop the switch off? or is this plastic damage?  Do you have a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the power circuit is torn, it's impossible to join it back. And definitely not with adhesive!